# Creating custom UIView, or child VCs

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

So, i have the following case. I got a custom tab layout, ie a horizontal UIScollview with paging. In each page there are some controls and a UITablevie, "bundles" in a custom UIView.

I create a ContainerVC, which has the scrollview, and then I initialize the two UIViews and add them as subviews in ContainerVC. To do so, i have created a custom UIView class and have have set this UIView as the owner of the .xib file. I also add the .xib class as my custom UIView.

Although this works, at least UI wise, i have some functionality problems, like the following.
In the init method of each UIView I initialize the view with

`Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, owner: self, options: nil)`

and then set the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDateSource to self.

However, when the data that feed the table arrives in the view, and i reload the tableview, nothing happens (the reload method is run in the main Thread), until i scroll the UITableview.

Is this the correct course of action?

VC

```
 func createUsageHistoryTabs() -> [Consumption] {
    var tabs = [Consumption]()

    let v1 = Consumption(pageIndex: 0, viewModel: viewModel)
    let v2 = Consumption(pageIndex: 1, viewModel: viewModel)

    tabs.append(v1)
    tabs.append(v2)
    return tabs
}

func setupScrollView() {

    if(!hasBeenCreated) {
        let tabs = createUsageHistoryTabs()
        scrollview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: container.frame.width, height: container.frame.height)
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(tabs.count), height: 1.0)
        scrollview.isPagingEnabled = true

        for i in 0 ..< tabs.count {
            let slideView = tabs[i]
            slideView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: scrollview.frame.origin.y, width: scrollview.frame.width, height: scrollview.frame.height)
            scrollview.addSubview(slideView)
        }

        hasBeenCreated.toggle()
    }


}
```

UIView:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

convenience init(pageIndex: Int, viewModel: UsageHistoryViewModel) {
    self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    self.pageIndex = pageIndex
    self.viewModel = viewModel

    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, owner: self, options: nil)
    contentView.fixInView(self)
    setupView()

    footer.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleFooterTap)))

    viewModel?.cdrDelegate = self

    tableView.register(EmptyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EmptyCell")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TVCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TVCell")

    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


}
```

Comment: You need to show some code. Common mistake is to instantiate your custom view as a local object in a func... when that func exits, the **view** may have been added, but the object (with the code) goes away. Make sure you have a class-level var to hold onto that object.

Comment: Added Some code!

Answer (score 0):

In this func:

```
func setupScrollView() {

    if(!hasBeenCreated) {

        // this line creates a LOCAL array
        let tabs = createUsageHistoryTabs()

        scrollview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: container.frame.width, height: container.frame.height)
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(tabs.count), height: 1.0)
        scrollview.isPagingEnabled = true

        for i in 0 ..< tabs.count {
            let slideView = tabs[i]
            slideView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: scrollview.frame.origin.y, width: scrollview.frame.width, height: scrollview.frame.height)
            scrollview.addSubview(slideView)
        }

        hasBeenCreated.toggle()
    }


}
```

You are creating a ***local*** array of `Consumption` objects. From each object, you add its ***view*** to your scrollView. As soon as that func exits, `tabs` no longer exists... it goes "out-of-scope".

You want to create a class-level var:

```
var tabsArray: [Consumption]?
```

and then modify that var instead of creating a local instance:

```
func setupScrollView() {

    if(!hasBeenCreated) {

        // this line creates a LOCAL array
        tabsArray = createUsageHistoryTabs()

        ...
```

Your custom classes should then be available until you delete them (or `tabsArray` goes out-of-scope).

You may need to make some other changes, but that should, at least, be a start.

---

**EDIT** *after comment discussion...*

If the tableviews are working, but not "updating" until the are scrolled - you said reload is being called on the main thread - you might try either of these options (or both... experiment):

```
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.setNeedsLayout()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Sure, i get that and i ll give it a try but then how the viewmodelDelegate works?
```viewModel?.cdrDelegate = self```

the cdrDelegate is associated with a protocol that has a function. The view impelements that protocol and the callback is correctly called.

Comment: Hmm... I may have misunderstood your original post - if so, sorry. So, with your current implementation (no changes as I suggested), your tableViews load and display the correct data, but only after you drag up/down to scroll? So the dataSource methods - `numberOfRows` and `cellForRowAt` are *not* called when you call `.reloadData()`, but they *are* called when you start to scroll the table?

Comment: @VictorBenetatos - see the edit at the bottom of my answer. Hopefully that will solve the issue.

Comment: Have tried layoutIfNeeded, with no success, but ill try the whole bundle.

Comment: Still nothing, thanks for the help, of course! I think maybe the wiring is wrong, cause i did it manually myself, meaning i created an UIView(.swift) and a .xib file manually and wired them up. And as you can tell i am no good at UIKit stuff :P

Is there a good way of starting a new custom UIView? I mean is there an option that gets you the swift file and the associated .xib, like in android when you create a fragment and you get the .xml file for free?

Comment: @VictorBenetatos - I don't really see anything fundamentally wrong with your approach. It may be something very simple, but tough to say at this point. If you can you put together a [mcve] I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'll dig into it some more and i'll come up with a sample if all else fails! Thanks again!